# How to Render Pages in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to make a home page but I can't render it's HTML file.

code:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
    if (req.url == '/') { 
        //inside here i want to render an html file
    }
    else {
        res.end('404');
    }
});

server.listen(1337); 

console.log('OPEN ON :1337')
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put in `res.send()` will be the response body. If you want to return html you will need to send a string with html eg `res.send(“<b>test</b>”)`.

However this will obviously not work in the long run. If you are looking for a simple node.js template based html solution, I would recommend looking into using a express server with a template library eg. handlebars.

https://expressjs.com/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

If you are looking for a way to serve a static .html file from disk, you might be better off using a simple web server instead (not node.js).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

or run an express server (see above) configured to serve static files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html